# How do I ensure my Linux program doesn't produce core dumps?

Tags: linux, security, coredump

I've got a program that keeps security-sensitive information (such as private keys) in memory, since it uses them over the lifetime of the program. Production versions of this program set RLIMIT_CORE to 0 to try to ensure that a core dump that might contain this sensitive information is never produced.

However, while this isn't mentioned in the `core(8)` manpage, the [apport documentation on the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#Crash_interception) claims,

> Note that even if ulimit is set to disabled core files (by specyfing a
>   core file size of zero using ulimit -c 0), apport will still capture
>   the crash.

Is there a way within my process (i.e., without relying on configuration of the system external to it) that I can ensure that a core dump of my process is never generated?

Note: I'm aware that there are plenty of methods (such as those mentioned in the comments below) where a user with root or process owner privileges could still access the sensitive data. What I'm aiming at here is preventing unintentional exposure of the sensitive data through it being saved to disk, being sent to the Ubuntu bug tracking system, or things like that. (Thanks to [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch) for making this explicit.)

Comment: Notice that a determined user could patch his own kernel running your application to still get core dumps.

Comment: And the process memory is also available thru `/proc/`

Answer (score 2):

According to [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_01), core dumps only happen in response to signals whose action is the default action and whose default action is to "terminate the process abnormally with additional actions".

So, if you scroll down to the list in [the description of signal.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html), everything with an "A" in the "Default Action" column is a signal you need to worry about.  Use [sigaction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) to catch all of them and just call `exit` (or `_exit`) in the signal handler.

I believe these are the only ways POSIX lets you generate a core dump.  Conceivably, Linux might have other "back doors" for this purpose; unfortunately, I am not enough of a kernel expert to be sure...

Comment: A good thought. However, this strikes me as very difficult to ensure that you've actually implemented it properly and it will work in all situations. Two potential errors I can think of off-hand: 1) I forget or misread your system-specific documentation and miss a signal, and 2) I catch something like SIGSEGV but my (obviously broken) program has put itself in a state where it cannot properly exit, and a core dump is produced anyway.

Comment: A fix for 1. is this: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/ <-- Download the latest version, uncompress it and look at the kill.c source. It has a function called list_signals that basically will enumerate all available signals in a standard compliant (if I am not mistaken) way. For 2. I suggest that if a signal is raised that is of such a severity that it would indicate a bad state, simply just exit there and then without trying to recover at all.